# Small circle (6x6px) is rendered asymmetrically

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a problem drawing symmetric circles with the Python Imaging Library. The following code should create a circle with a diameter of 6 px. What it draws is a unsymmetric "circle" shown in die picture. Does anybody has a solution? This problem occurs for all evan diameters.[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('1', (8, 8), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.ellipse((1, 1, 6, 6), fill = 'black', outline ='black')

img.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug on PIL? What you will notice is that all even diameters produce this artifact, odd diameters seem to not have this artifact Try for example: `draw.ellipse((1, 1, 400, 400), fill = 'black', outline ='black')` vs. `draw.ellipse((1, 1, 401, 401), fill = 'black', outline ='black')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is right. Thats a Bug in the Pillow Package. It should be fixed with the next update (3.3.0) on first of July.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that's because [drawing circles is hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) and your result is what the algorithm used by PIL produces for such small circles. You could draw your own "circle" using a polygon.

One could argue however that ellipses with equal radii should at least be symmetric...